# EnvUplevel with tabular in exam class

Tags: exam

I am wondering why does the `EnvUplevel` environment in the `exam`class doesn't work with tables (and I suspect figures maybe too). I have:

```
\documentclass{exam}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[top=1in, height=9in, left=0.75in, right=0.75in, paperwidth=8.5in, paperheight=11in]{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\begin{questions}
    \question
        \lipsum[8]
        \begin{center}
            \begin{tabular}{ccccccc}
                \toprule
                \bfseries \parbox{2.4cm}{\centering Temperatura \si{\degreeCelsius}}    &   \bfseries Amprenavir    &   \bfseries Indinavir &   \bfseries Lopinavir &   \bfseries Nelfinavir    &   \bfseries Ritonavir &   \bfseries Saquinavir    \\  \midrule
                5                                   &   1.85    &   1.88    &   0.506   &   0.912   &   1.93    &   0.146   \\  
                25                                  &   4.76    &   3.44    &   0.654   &   2.17    &   2.59    &   0.4251  \\  
                \bottomrule
            \end{tabular}
        \end{center}
    \begin{parts}
        \part \lipsum[5]
        \begin{EnvUplevel}
            \lipsum[8]
            \begin{center}
                \begin{tabular}{ccccccc}
                    \toprule
                    \bfseries \parbox{2.4cm}{\centering Temperatura \si{\degreeCelsius}}    &   \bfseries Amprenavir    &   \bfseries Indinavir &   \bfseries Lopinavir &   \bfseries Nelfinavir    &   \bfseries Ritonavir &   \bfseries Saquinavir    \\  \midrule
                    5                                   &   1.85    &   1.88    &   0.506   &   0.912   &   1.93    &   0.146   \\  
                    25                                  &   4.76    &   3.44    &   0.654   &   2.17    &   2.59    &   0.4251  \\  
                    \bottomrule
                \end{tabular}
            \end{center}
        \end{EnvUplevel}
        \part \lipsum[2]
    \end{parts}
\end{questions}

\end{document}
```

Which produces:

[image]

You may notice two things. The most important one is that both tables are not aligned the same, even though they should be at the same level. The second one is the spacing between the text and the table is lost when using the EnvUplevel, but I think that's easily fixed with a `\vspace` (although why would that happen, just out of curiosity?). Is there a fix for the alignment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with this solution is that it won't break across pages.

It should be noted that exam class implements its own lists, but not using `\trivlist`.  OTOH, UpLevel has no corresponding list counterpart, other than `\endtrivlist`.

```
\documentclass{exam}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[top=1in, height=9in, left=0.75in, right=0.75in, paperwidth=8.5in, paperheight=11in]{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\begin{questions}
    \question
        \lipsum[8]
        \begin{center}
            \begin{tabular}{ccccccc}
                \toprule
                \bfseries \parbox{2.4cm}{\centering Temperatura \si{\degreeCelsius}}    &   \bfseries Amprenavir    &   \bfseries Indinavir &   \bfseries Lopinavir &   \bfseries Nelfinavir    &   \bfseries Ritonavir &   \bfseries Saquinavir    \\  \midrule
                5                                   &   1.85    &   1.88    &   0.506   &   0.912   &   1.93    &   0.146   \\  
                25                                  &   4.76    &   3.44    &   0.654   &   2.17    &   2.59    &   0.4251  \\  
                \bottomrule
            \end{tabular}
        \end{center}
    \begin{parts}
        \part \lipsum[5]
        \begin{EnvUplevel}
          \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
            \parskip=\baselineskip
            \lipsum[8]
            \begin{center}
                \begin{tabular}{ccccccc}
                    \toprule
                    \bfseries \parbox{2.4cm}{\centering Temperatura \si{\degreeCelsius}}    &   \bfseries Amprenavir    &   \bfseries Indinavir &   \bfseries Lopinavir &   \bfseries Nelfinavir    &   \bfseries Ritonavir &   \bfseries Saquinavir    \\  \midrule
                    5                                   &   1.85    &   1.88    &   0.506   &   0.912   &   1.93    &   0.146   \\  
                    25                                  &   4.76    &   3.44    &   0.654   &   2.17    &   2.59    &   0.4251  \\  
                    \bottomrule
                \end{tabular}
            \end{center}
          \end{minipage}
        \end{EnvUplevel}
        \part \lipsum[2]
    \end{parts}
\end{questions}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It works for my purposes, great! I'll leave the question open to see if someone comes up with a better way/fix. I'll accept if no one has any other ideas.